# List of all Minecraft crafting recipes for crafting web

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-bedrock-edition, minecraft-data-packs, minecraft-addons

I am attempting to build some sort of crafting web to find the most efficient crafting trees and which items need to be farmed to craft every other remaining item in the game. An old example is shown below:

[image: An old Minecraft Production Web]

This example was around many years ago and the game has obviously developed a lot since then so doing it by hand would not be a very efficient use of my time. Instead, I'm programming it but to do this I need a list of every craft/smelt/brew etc possible in Minecraft (preferably for Java Edition).

I first tried looking at the Bedrock Edition addon pack found on [here](https://www.minecraft.net/en-us/addons) which does contain a rather extensive list of crafting recipes however, they are missing large amounts. Namely sticks and other wooden items. The crimson/warped variants seem to have replaced these crafting recipes. Crafting table and other fundamental recipes are also missing.

I then tried looking at Java Edition datapacks but was unable to find a vanilla simulating pack.

I am aware I could just web scrape the entire official wiki but that again seems like quite a poor solution.

In terms of format literally any list would be enough as I could convert it into whatever format I need after.

Comment: Which specific version of Minecraft are you looking for? If you narrow it down to a single one (e.g. Java Edition), I think this question would be on-topic.

Comment: I don't really understand why this was closed?

Comment: A list of all crafting recipes is too broad to be answered.

Comment: @Wrigglenite he/she asked for where he could find them

Comment: The answer below contains the correct answer. Frankly, I wasn't really bothered about what version, there are so few differences really. Should I still edit the question now?

Comment: @Jay Hales you don't need to edit anything unless you think its needed. This will probably get reopened because we just need 1 more vote, weve already got 4

Comment: You don't need to edit anything because the question is too broad to be answered. A list of all crafting recipes is simply too much for the scope of a single question.

Comment: But it was already answered perfectly, so how could it be too big of a scope?

Comment: @Wrigglenite You are extremely stubborn. The question intent and scope is clear, and it already has a satisfactory answer but you still refuse to accept facts presented in front of you and go about what you think was requested instead of what really was requested.

Comment: Sorry for the horrible way to greet you, we promise this doesn't normally happen!

Comment: That's okay, don't worry about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Java Edition, open the [`.minecraft` folder](https://help.minecraft.net/hc/en-us/articles/360035131551) (on Windows: `%APPDATA%\.minecraft`), then locate the `versions` folder, and the version you want your map for, within - for this example I'll use `1.16.2` - there should be a `1.16.2.json` and `1.16.2.jar` file inside (if .jar is missing, use the MC launcher to download and install the desired version, by creating a new installantion).

Make a copy of the [version].jar file somewhere, and change the file extension (rename the file) to 1.16.2.zip, then open in an archivizer program, like 7zip. Find `data\minecraft\recipes\` folder and extract its contents. It contains the list of all craftable items, and you can use the `json` files in your program to generate the database to build the basis of the map - although in certain cases you will need some manual intervention, in case of special crafts like firework rockets, where a variety of ingredients produces different fireworks, and all the .json file says about the recipe is `"type": "minecraft:crafting_special_firework_rocket"`

See [wiki](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Tutorials/Creating_a_data_pack#Shaped_crafting) for info on the format.

If you want sources of resources (like on the map), you may also check the `loot_tables` folder (next to `recipes`) - although it will require quite a bit of manual curating to exclude ultra-obscure sources (baby panda -> slime balls), treasure chests and all the way too obvious sources (cobblestone block -> cobblestone).